# HTTP webpage is showing "Not Secure" in Chrome

Tags: https, security, security-certificate, http, google-chrome

I've called GoDaddy a few different times and they said that it looks like it is a problem with my HTML file.  Except, my HTML file is the basic outline of a webpage, nothing fancy at all.

Chrome still says that the webpage is, "Not Secure" with the big red *x* over it.

I'm not sure what to do to fix it, I don't have any personal information on the site nor am I collecting any information from visitors (it's sort of an information site).  I shouldn't need an SSL certificate because I am not hosting anything privately.

Comment: As of October of 2017, Google Chrome started marking pages without an SSL that have either a password or credit card field as “Not secure”. If you have either of these on any page (including inside iframes), you'll need to obtain an SSL. See their blog announcing this here:  [Chromium Blog - Next steps toward more connection security](https://blog.chromium.org/2017/04/next-steps-toward-more-connection.html)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a move to make the web more secure. Additionally, it protects all visitors to your site. The long-term solution is to implement SSL on your website(s), as all websites will eventually need to adopt the use of SSL certificates.

According to [Google's Developer Blog:](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/10/avoid-not-secure-warn)

> Eventually, Chrome will show a Not Secure warning for all pages served
>   over HTTP, regardless of whether or not the page contains sensitive
>   input fields. Even if you adopt one of the more targeted resolutions
>   above, you should plan to migrate your site to use HTTPS for all
>   pages.

You absolutely need an SSL certificate. I am aware of the fact that they are overpriced at just about every registrar. To save some money, the Linux Foundation has a website which offers free SSL certificates, called * https://letsencrypt.org although this route may be slightly more labor intensive as it relates to installation vs. simply buying from Godaddy.

Comment: The Linux Foundation had nothing to do with founding LetsEncrypt. In fact, iirc, it was originally formed by Mozilla and is now supported by many but it is not a Linux Foundation only project.

Comment: Not to go on about it but letsencrypt.org is owned by ISRG and the Linux Foundation only fairly recently started providing "organizational management", whatever that is. http://www.eweek.com/security/let-s-encrypt-becomes-linux-foundation-collaborative-project

Comment: @Rob thanks for clarifying, I should not have assumed nor jumped to that conclusion.